# How to make this text rotator to be read sequentially and repeat

Tags: javascript

This is a script that functions randomize.

```
function rotateEvery(sec) {
var Quotation=new Array()

Quotation[0] = 'Example 1..';
Quotation[1] = 'Example 2..';
Quotation[2] = 'Example 3..';
Quotation[3] = 'Example 4..';
Quotation[4] = 'Example 5..';    

var which = Math.round(Math.random()*(Quotation.length - 1));
document.getElementById('textrotator').innerHTML = Quotation[which];

setTimeout('rotateEvery('+sec+')', sec*1000);
}
rotateEvery(4);
```

i want it to be read sequentially from quotation[0] to quotation[n] then repeat. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hY26L/1/

```
var counter = 0;
var Quotation=new Array()
Quotation[0] = 'Example 1..';
Quotation[1] = 'Example 2..';
Quotation[2] = 'Example 3..';
Quotation[3] = 'Example 4..';
Quotation[4] = 'Example 5..';    

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('textrotator').innerHTML = Quotation[counter++ % Quotation.length] 
}

rotate();
window.setInterval(rotate, 4000);
```

% is modulo (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and basically gives you the remainder from division. So 0 % 4 is 0, 1 % 4 is 1, ..., 4 % 4 is 0... and so on.

`setInterval` is like `setTimeout` but it fires every X miliseconds rather than just once